# How to compare timestamps in MySql table and select older than given time period

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp, date-format

Timestamps and date formats were allways puzzling me a little bit. Let's say we have a MySql table where date column is in timestamp format.

I'd like to ask what is the easiest or simplest way how to find all table rows older than, for example 1 week.

Comment: try this link www.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider one week back from now including the `hour-min-sec` using `date_sub` function you can get it as

```
mysql> select date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) as d ;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2015-05-26 15:33:15 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So the query becomes

```
select * from table_name
where date_column < date_sub(now(), interval 1 week)
```

Now if you just want to consider the date part it would be

```
where date(date_column) < date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 week)
```

The problem with this approach is that for large data-set even if the date_column is indexed it will fail to use it and hence performance issue.

So get the datetime value from midnight one week from now as

```
mysql> select date_format(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 week),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as d ;
+---------------------+
| d                   |
+---------------------+
| 2015-05-26 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

and the where query becomes

```
select * from table_name
where 
date_column < date_format(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 week),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: excellent solution, didn't know about date_sub() function, thx :)